# Permission 'cloudmessaging.messages.create' denied on resource

Tags: c#, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add notifications to my application
The application is Android, and I am trying to test the notification sending with postman
I am receiving my Authorization Bearer via a console app and using it in postman for testing
This is the code for the Authorization Bearer

```
public static async Task<string> getToken()
{
    try
    {
        // Create an explicit ServiceAccountCredential credential
        var credential = await GoogleCredential.FromFile({pathToJsonFile})                                            
                     .CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging")
                     .UnderlyingCredential
                     .GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();

        return credential;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The `{pathToJsonFile}` contains the key file I got from `console.cloud.google.com` site for a `service_account` I created
I gave the `service_account` `owner` and `Service Account Admin` roles
I am trying to send the notification via postman as such
[image: Headers]

The name of the project (hidden in blue in the url) I got it from `console.firebase.google.com/project/.../`

```
{
  "message": {
    "token": "{tokenIGotFromAndroidDevice}",
    "notification": {
      "title": "body",
      "body": "Title"
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "1",
      "message": "message"
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'cloudmessaging.messages.create' denied on resource '//cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/...' (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "resource": "projects/...",
          "permission": "cloudmessaging.messages.create"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use project ID not project name